# How to read from 2 tables via ADODB

Tags: mysql, adodb

How i can read from 2 tables with the same structure ( names ) but different content?

I have 3 tables, normally before i had an big table with 1.500.000 rows which i split it in 3 tables 500.000 rows each

Tables Structure: ID - Title - Add_Time

Table1: videos_data3
Max ID: 1500000
Min ID: 1000001

Table2: videos_data2
Max ID: 1000000
Min ID: 500001

Table3: videos_data1
Max ID: 500000
Min ID: 1

I'm trying using this command:

```
   $sql                   = "select ID, Title from videos_data3, videos_data2, videos_data1 where " . $this->filter . " ORDER BY ID Desc";
   $rs                    = $db->Execute($sql);
   $loaded                = $rs->GetRows();
```

but this command is not working, but if i use just 1 table example videos_data3 is working ... how i can make this to work ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meant to use `UNION ALL`

```sql
SELECT ID, Title FROM videos_data3 WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Title FROM videos_data2 WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Title FROM videos_data1 WHERE ...
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/754d1/2)** demo

Further reading

- [UNION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html)